# apply jquery effect on dynamically added div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function myfunction(id){
//code 

$("#mydiv").hide();
};
```

But 'mydiv' is dynamically added , and the function is not working .

Comment: is `myfunction(id)` is calling in a click event??

Comment: There is no reason for this not to work. `$("#mydiv")` is not cached, it is evaluated each time you call it.

Comment: Also you might want to write down the following: 1. What do you want to happen? 2. What happens instead? These 2 questions are quite important in finding the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the part of the code you shared seems to be fine, I suspect that there is something else wrong with your code.

Try to [debug](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) it. It is not that hard and let's you figure out errors on your own much faster than looking at your code really hard.

First if would be good to know if you reach that line of code in question. You can open the developer console and add a breakpoint to the line in question, or you can add `alert("this line is reached and executed")` in your code, and then you will know if that line is reached and executed.

If you reached the line in question, it would be good to know things about what is happening there:

For example it would be good to know if `$("#mydiv")` matches anything. If you are afraid of the developer console, you can always try: `alert($("#mydiv").length)`. If it's 0, there is nothing matched, if it's `1`, you have matched an element that will be hidden if you call `$("#mydiv").hide()`. If it's `0`, you haven't been able to match an element. That means that there is currently **no elements in your DOM with the id of `mydiv`**. It does not matter if it should have been added dinamically or should be there from the start, it's not there. You might have made a spelling mistake in the id.

Since you are matching something added dynamically by it's id, it is possible that you already have an element with the ID `mydiv`. If there is more elements with the same ID, only the first one will be matched! More than one elements with the same ID is not just bad practice, it's invalid, and will possibly lead to more bugs and headaches later.

If you are sure that you match the correct element and it's not hidden when you call `$("#mydiv").hide()`, than there is always ways to look for the problem: for example if you open the javascript developer console, the javascript errors will be listed there. Be sure to check them if they are related to this problem.

Happy bug hunting!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're calling `$("#mydiv").hide();` *after* you've added `#mydiv`. The code itself will work absolutely fine, provided you've already added `#mydiv`.